# How to batch print folders of MS Office documents?

Tags: printing, ms-office

We have workers’ reports that are kept in folders. Mostly the files are saved as Word and Excel documents. I need to print them for each business meeting and have to open each folder individually. I wonder if there is a possibility to simplify the process.

Comment: Search for the required files to have a list of results, Select All, Right click "Print"?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for bulk printing there exists the software called Print Conductor. Here is the description of the files it works with: http://www.print-conductor.com/articles/print-documents.html. You will need to specify the folders, and the program will drag the files from there creating lists of files for printing. Then you will be able to print them all at once.